# при запуску сервера на node js вылезает ошибка: document is not defined. все работало пока я не попробовал подключить bootstrap

Tags: node.js

я сейчас изучаю node js и одновременно узнаю что такое bootstrap. я сделал все так как было указанно на сайте bootstrap, но у меня после запуска сервера вылезает ошибка:   document is not defined и разные пути, вот такие: bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js а сама ошибка выглядит вот так:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at enableDismissTrigger (C:\1 PROGRAM\WEB\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:826:21)
at C:\1 PROGRAM\WEB\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:908:3
at C:\1 PROGRAM\WEB\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:7:83
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\1 PROGRAM\WEB\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:10:3)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
```

```js
const express = require('express')
const bootstrap = require('bootstrap')

const app = express()
app.set('view angine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs')
})

const PORT = 8080

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log(`http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>test</h1>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

скорее всего я как-то не правильно установил bootstrap и скорее всего невозможно что бы вы мне помогли т.к. мало информации, но если я что-то упустил напишите пожалуйста

Comment: Бутстрап работает только в браузере. Удалите импорт бутстрапа из ноды